# On algebraic operations involving $-\infty$ and $+\infty$

Tags: infinity

$-\infty$ and $+\infty$ are two mathematical objects that we attach to the real number system to extend it. These objects are governed by a set of properties. However, I'm confused on a few points. Any clarification on these points would be greatly appreciated.

$(i)$ Are $\frac{1}{\infty}$ and $\frac{1}{-\infty}$ indeterminate$?$ Or they are equal to $0?$

$(ii)$ Is $\left(+\infty\right)^{\left(+\infty\right)}$ indeterminate or $+\infty?$

$(iii)$ For $-\infty<x<0,$ $\left(+\infty\right)^x=?$

$(iv)$ $\left(+\infty\right)^{\left(-\infty\right)}=?$

$(v)$ $0^{\left(+\infty\right)}=?$

$(vi)$ For $-\infty<x<0,$ $x^{\left(+\infty\right)}=?$

$(vii)$ $\left(-\infty\right)^{\left(+\infty\right)}=?$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would say that all such expressions are best avoided.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I'd still like to know what they are? Indeterminate? Or we assign some value to it?

Comment: (i)=0, (ii)=$+\infty$, (iii) = $+\infty$ for $x>0$, $=0$ for $x<0$ and undefined for $x=0$. (iv) $=0$. (v) $=0$. (vi) $=+\infty$ for $x>1$, $=0$ for $0<x<1$, $=1$ for $x=1$, undefined for $x<0$. (vii) undefined.

Comment: "Indeterminate" only has meaning in the context of limits.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I understand. But how do I understand that an expression is indeterminate? For example in limiting argument (as in comment below Jose's answer, we cannot decide whether $0 \times \infty = 0$ or $\infty$..

Comment: @Dragon: That is easy: An _expression_ is never "indeterminate". The only thing the word "indeterminate" applies to is _forms of limits_, which is a different thing from an expression. A limit of the form "$0\times \infty$" (which really ought to be written as something like $({\to}0)\times({\to}\infty)$ such that this confusion is avoided) has an indeterminate form. But $0\times\infty$ is not an expression because $\infty$ is not a thing that you can do arithmetic on.

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. They are equal to $0$.
2. It is $+\infty$.
3. $0$.
4. $0$.
5. $0$.
6. It's indeterminate.
7. It has no meaning.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can you give me some source where I can read about these term and why they are assigned the corresponding values?

Comment: @Dragon He cannot even compute them properly.

Comment: @Hellen So these are sort of axioms that come with the objects $-\infty$ and $+\infty ?$ $($i.e. one cannot derive them from a smaller set of axioms$)$

Comment: @Dragon No. I was thinking in terms of limits. Consider the first point, for instance. If a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $\pm\infty$, then $(1/x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $0$. I can justify my other answers with the same type of argument.

Comment: Okay. That's a nice argument. So in this line, $0 \times \left(+\infty\right) = 0$. $($Take $x_n=0$ and $y_n=n)$ for instance. On the other hand, taking $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $y_n=n^2$ gives $0 \times \left(+\infty\right)=+\infty$. That seems odd. So what really is the value of $0 \times \left(+\infty\right),$ if it is not indeterminate?

Comment: @Dragon Usually $0$ is understood as the 'normal number' zero, whereas only $\infty$ and $-\infty$ are understood as limits.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos how do you say $0^{+\infty}$ is $0$? Take $a_n=((-1)^n\frac{1}{n})^{n/2}$, $n=1,2,\dots$. Is this sequence goes to $0$?

Comment: @Dragon No. $0\times(+\infty)$ is indeterminate. Note that I used *arbitrary* sequences, whereas you used *specifc* ones. From your approach, all that can be deduced is that $0\times(+\infty)$ either is indeterminate or it is equal to $0$.

Comment: I understand. Thanks!

Comment: @MANMAID If $\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}x_n=0$ and $\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}y_n=+\infty$, then $\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}{x_n}^{y_n}=0$. Of course, in order for this to make sense, one must assume that $(\forall n\in{\mathbb N}):x_N\geqslant0$.